# JSON Nesting Too Deep (Using OJ)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

The problem:

`JSON::NestingError: nesting of 101 is too deep`

I've tried adding the `:max_nesting => 120` to my `JSON.parse` line with no avail.

Then switched to OJ to see if that would change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really have 101 levels of nesting? Do you really need it?

Comment: I'm calling an external api on a large scale. I don't see a way around it...

Answer (score 2):

Calll JSON.parse with a max_nesting option. It works for me.

```
> o = JSON.parse(File.read(Rails.root.join("deep.json")))
JSON::NestingError: nesting of 101 is too deep
> o = JSON.parse(File.read(Rails.root.join("deep.json")),max_nesting: 150)
# { Big ol' deeply nested hash }
```